# Why won't my MySQL statement execute in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I can't seem to find anybody else with this issue, but it just seems like I can't execute statements at all.

Here's my code:

```
xroxy.getProxies(function(error, proxies) {
        console.log(proxies);
        connection.prepare('INSERT INTO `proxies` (`ip`, `port`) VALUES (INET_ATON(?), ?)', function(err, statement) {
                for (var key in proxies) {
                        if (!proxies.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                        console.log(key + ": " + proxies[key]);
                        statement.execute([key, proxies[key]], function(err, rows, columns) {
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(rows);
                        });
                        statement.close();
                        //console.log('test');
                }
        });

        connection.end(function(err) {

        });
}, 100);
```

Before using `statement.execute()` I tried to just use `connection.execute()` and that didn't seem to work either. I've got mysql2 in debug mode and it's showing me that the statements are *preparing* (and even did when I used `connection.execute()` but past that won't insert anything into the database.

The callback never seems to get called from `statement.execute()` nor `connection.execute()`

Comment: Where are you adding your prepared statement parameters?

Comment: They come from xroxy.getProxies' callback

Comment: hi Rob, can you make simple reproducible example (including schema creation) and put it as issue on mysql2 github ? I'll try to help

Comment: looks like you are closing connection before any statement is executed. Try to count the number of completed execute() calls and in last callback do `connection.end()`